# SHGetFileInfo function cause unhandled exception

Tags: visual-c++, com, mfc, windows-shell

I have application with CMFCShellTreeCtrl on one of it's dialog and it is crashing when running on some Win8 machines. It happen when tree control trying to initialize and calls SHGetFileInfo in this part of afxshelltreectrl.cpp:

```
int CMFCShellTreeCtrl::OnGetItemIcon(LPAFX_SHELLITEMINFO pItem, BOOL bSelected)
{
    ENSURE(pItem != NULL);

    SHFILEINFO sfi;

    UINT uiFlags = SHGFI_PIDL | SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX | SHGFI_SMALLICON;

    if (bSelected)
    {
        uiFlags |= SHGFI_OPENICON;
    }
    else
    {
        uiFlags |= SHGFI_LINKOVERLAY;
    }

    if (SHGetFileInfo((LPCTSTR)pItem->pidlFQ, 0, &sfi, sizeof(sfi), uiFlags))
    {
        return sfi.iIcon;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Application was build in VS2010 on Win7 32-bit.
I could not replicate this bug on VM so I debug remotely on client PC.
I compared the values ​​of arguments for SHGetFileInfo function, and they looked the same on my machine and the client's, except the memory addresses.

Call stack after exception:
[screenshot](http://bayimg.com/JaALkaAff)

WinDbg log:

```
ModLoad: 02b70000 02bc9000   cmd.exe 
ModLoad: 60780000 607ca000   C:\windows\SysWOW64\mscoree.dll
ModLoad: 60700000 6077a000   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll
ModLoad: 711b0000 71250000   C:\windows\SysWOW64\sxs.dll
ModLoad: 60150000 606ff000   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll
ModLoad: 70e30000 70ecb000   C:\windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.6910_none_d089c358442de345\MSVCR80.dll
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.6910_none_d089c358442de345\MSVCR80.dll - 
ModLoad: 5f650000 6014a000   C:\windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\mscorlib\7f763721bf47dc8d58ec21cb64cbec91\mscorlib.ni.dll
ModLoad: 71770000 71778000   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\culture.dll
(c18.227c): CLR exception - code e0434f4d (first chance)
(c18.227c): Access violation - code c0000005 (first chance)
First chance exceptions are reported before any exception handling.
This exception may be expected and handled.
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\windows\SysWOW64\combase.dll - 
eax=002d0068 ebx=80040154 ecx=04b1f654 edx=04b1f678 esi=0018b654 edi=76cbbda0
eip=002d0068 esp=0018b63c ebp=0018b648 iopl=0         nv up ei ng nz ac pe cy
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010297
002d0068 ??              ???
```

According to the call stack error occurs in some COM functions.
I am not familiar with COM so may be some one can help me to find the reason why SHGetFileInfo cause exception.

Comment: Are you sure `pItem->pidlFQ` is valid? And that `CoInitialize`/`OleInitialize` has been called on the thread?

Comment: Jonathan, thank you, CoInitialize in the beginning of OnInitDialog() solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

c0000005 is memory accessing exception. check whether your pItem has been initialized before calling this function. Or you can check whether 'pItem->pidlFQ' is valid.